# Are elements with mismatched prefixes allowed?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

The ["Common Syntatic Constructs" section of the XML 1.0 Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn) contains the following note:

> The Namespaces in XML Recommendation assigns a meaning to names
>   containing colon characters. Therefore, authors should not use the
>   colon in XML names except for namespace purposes, but **XML processors
>   must accept the colon as a name character.**

This means that the following is invalid XML:

```
<xhtml:span
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xhtml:a>Anchor text</html:a>
</xhtml:span>
```

However, [the "Qualified Names" section of the Namespaces in XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames) contains this statement:

> Note that the prefix functions only as a placeholder for a namespace
>   name. **Applications SHOULD use the namespace name, not the prefix**,
>   in constructing names whose scope extends beyond the containing
>   document.

This leads to an ambiguity. When something like this happens, does the XML recommendation have precedence, rendering the above document invalid, or should a namespace-aware XML processor first convert prefixes to their appropriate namespaces and consider the above document valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Namespaces recommendation states in section 7 (Conformance):

> To conform to this specification, a document MUST be well-formed
>   according to the XML 1.0 specification [XML].

Therefore prefixes used in the start and end tag must match.